# How can I load Word2vec with Gensim without getting an AttributeError?

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I am new to Gensim, and I am trying to load my given (pre-trained) Word2vec model. I have 2 files: *xxxx.model.wv* and a bigger one *xxxx.model.wv.syn0.npy*.

When I call the following line:

```
gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('xxxx.model.wv')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'EuclideanKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'negative'
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: I'm positive you will have to show more code. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: More code is required. Also, look into the difference between loading a model and loading model.wv to load Keyedvectors. Look into https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html for detailed documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your `xxxx.model.wv` file was a saved full `Word2Vec` model object?

That error suggests it was instead a `EuclideanKeyedVectors` – just the vectors, and not a full model with all properties like `negative` – so you might need to load it as that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same question.
The main reason is that the model is not a full model object.
So, you can load the model use "gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load(model_path)" or "gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)".
I hope it can solve your question.